# Make UIImagePickerController set selected image to multiple UIImageViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 3 buttons, and 3 UIImageViews, and all of the buttons open a UIImagePickerController. I want button 1 to open the UIImagePickerController, and then set the selected image to UIImageView 1, and button 2 to open a UIImagePickerController, and set the selected image to UIImageView 2, ect. How can this be done? Thank you!

Comment: There are many ways to do this.Please show what you have tried. you can use bool values to make sure button 1 is clicked, in which case after you pick the image, it will be added to imageView1. Same for the remaining two!

Answer (score 2):

You can set tags (`1,2,3`) to your buttons to determine what button is pressed by user. Store this value into some variable and use it later to determine into which UIImageView you need to set UIImage received from UIImagePickerController.

Update.
Tags can be set right in Interface Bulder or from code:

```
button1.tag = 1;
```

To store current tag use variable in your controller:

```
@interface NameOfYourController : UIViewController
{
    NSInteger currentTag;
}
```

To get button tag use this in button touch up inside event:

```
-(void)buttonTap:(UIButton *)sender
{
    currentTag = sender.tag;
}
```

When UIImagePickerController calls media picking finished, use stored tag:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *img = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if (currentTag==1)
        imageView1.image = image;
    else if (currentTag==2)
        imageView2.image = image;
    else if (currentTag==3)
        imageView3.image = image;
}
```

Comment: can you provide me with a code example for setting those tags to the buttons, and an example of how id use said tag to choose which UIImageView to set?